# If statement not returning the correct value

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. I am wanting to code to look at my named ranged for a specific value. Then go compare to the last cell in a specific column. Then take the first character and see what number that is. So my named range for an example would be 1 and the last cell in my specific column would be 1.02. I want it to pull the first character from the left and see if they are the same. However, ever time I run the code I keep returning the false if statement portion.

```
Dim TimeStamp As Range
Dim LastItem As Range
Dim LastItemNumber As Range

Set LastItemNumber = Range("C500").End(xlUp).End(xlUp)
Set TimeStamp = Range("C500").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)
Set LastItem = Range("C500").End(xlUp)


LastItemNumber.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
TimeStamp = Now

If Range("Meeting_Number") = Left(LastItemNumber, 1) Then
    MsgBox ("True")
    LastItemNumber.FormulaR1C1 = "1.02"
        Else
    MsgBox ("False")
End If
```

I am expecting the result to populate the message box and say true. Then input "1.02" into the last cell in that column.

Comment: so your named range is a single cell?  and on what sheet is it (the one you're looking or other)?  as written, only the first cell in the named range, using its full string, is compared to a single value

Comment: Additionally, have you tried using `RoundDown()` for both values to compare?  Also, `Range("Meeting_Number").value = Left(LastItemNumber.value, 1)`